# Remove Synergy completely from computer

Tags: uninstall, synergy

I found synergy too complicated for me and uninstalled it. Now I have a Icon in the taskbar and cannot remove it .I cannot edit the registry either, does not allow me Can anyone help

Comment: Did you try Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features, and then clicking on Synergy in the list and clicking Uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

Install Synergy again, this time use [Revo Free](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have your IT install synergy? It sounds like you're not an admin user. What OS are you running Mac, XP, Vista, 7, or GNU/Linux? I ask because synergy runs on most things (windows, mac os, GNU/linux). If you aren't an admin user and you try to uninstall something it might remove it from the list but you could be blocked by file system permission issues.

If you had it installed by IT, have them install it again and uninstall it from an admin account.